# Can Visual Studio use an .editorconfig not in the directory hierarchy?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2019, editorconfig

We have a very large number of solutions spread across a wide number of repositories which do not always share a directory hierarchy in a way that makes it easy for us to update an .editorconfig such that it applies to all projects/solutions in the organization. We currently apply all of our code analysis configuration via an internal NuGet package and I was hoping we could include our organization-wide .editorconfig settings in this way as well?

I tried a quick experiment adding the following to a project to see if linked files would be honored (since we could simply add this to a props file we already have in the NuGet package), but it does not appear to be honored currently.

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="C:\SomeAlternatePath\ECTest\.editorconfig" Link=".editorconfig" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Is there some other MSBuild property or mechanism we could use to better facilitate this without literally writing a duplicate file to every solution/project/repo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there some other MSBuild property or mechanism we could use to
>   better facilitate this without literally writing a duplicate file to
>   every solution/project/repo?

I'm afraid the answer is negative. Cause the `.editorconfig` file have nothing to do with msbuild or `xx.csproj`. Only **file hierarchy** can affect the behavior how the config file works. More details please check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-portable-custom-editor-options?view=vs-2019).

**Some tests:**

When I right-click project=>add `.editorconfig` to add this file in current project, there's one line added to the `xx.csproj`: `<None Include=".editorconfig"/>`.

If we set the `indent_size = 32`, it works for current project. Now we can `right-click that file=>Exclude from Project` to remove that file from current project system. (This action will remove the `<None Include=".editorconfig"/>` in xx.csproj, but the file is still in the same folder where xx.csproj exists)

Now reload the project, the settings(indent_size=32) still works. So it's obvious if we place this file in project directory, then it will take effect, no matter if we have definitions about it in project file(`xx.csproj`).

**Suggestions:**

According to your description, all your projects use the same `.editorconfig` file. Since this file's working scope is affected by file hierarchy, you can reduce some meaningless work by:

1.Place that file in Solution folder, it will work for all projects under that solution folder

2.Place that file in `repos`(C:\Users\xxx\source\repos) folder, it will work for all solutions and projects under this folder.

3.So if most of your solutions are under path `C:\somepath`, place that file here, all projects under that path will benefit from that. And about **precedence** in `file hierarchy` please see [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-portable-custom-editor-options?view=vs-2019#file-hierarchy-and-precedence).

Hope all above makes some help :)

Comment: Yeah, your explanation matches my understanding now, although it seems to me the setting probably shouldn't be called "project coding conventions" if the settings have nothing to do with the project. I have some additional conversation over here ( https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/issues/1700 ) regarding it. Since our goal is to share these settings with ALL developers for ALL projects, we may just have people map a git repository to their root dev folder that ignores everything except .gitignore and .editorconfig (so that it doesn't track files in any nested directories)

Comment: There is now discussion on the official Roslyn repository about how this might be made possible: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/19028